# Trouble compiling tweak on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm currently trying to compile a tweak using theos on my iPhone 5s on 8.1.1 over ssh.

I used an open-sourced one called EasyRespring that I found on github which is claimed to be iOS 8 compatible.

After copying all the files from it and running make, I'm thrown a slew of errors that I'm having trouble deciphering.

I can provide any extra information if necessary.

```
drop-it-like-its-hotspot:/private/var/easyrespring root# make
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm64/iphone.mk:43: Targeting iOS 4.0 and higher is not supported with iphone-gcc. Forcing clang.
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm64/iphone.mk:53: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak EasyRespring...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from <built-in>:181:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from /private/var/easyrespring/theos/Prefix.pch:4:
In file included from /private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9:
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:18:1: error: 
      C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 5_0, "UIAcceleration has been replaced by t...
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:18:26: error: 
      invalid suffix '_0' on integer constant
NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 5_0, "UIAcceleration has been replaced by t...
                         ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:18:98: error: 
      expected ';' after top level declarator
  ...5_0, "UIAcceleration has been replaced by the CoreMotion framework")
                                                                         ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:26:1: error: 
      unexpected '@' in program
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIAccelerationValue x;
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:27:1: error: 
      unexpected '@' in program
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIAccelerationValue y;
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:28:1: error: 
      unexpected '@' in program
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIAccelerationValue z;
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:30:1: error: 
      '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
@end
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:32:1: error: 
      C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 5_0, "UIAccelerometer has been replaced by ...
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:32:26: error: 
      invalid suffix '_0' on integer constant
NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 5_0, "UIAccelerometer has been replaced by ...
                         ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:32:99: error: 
      expected ';' after top level declarator
  ...5_0, "UIAccelerometer has been replaced by the CoreMotion framework")
                                                                          ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:45:1: error: 
      unexpected '@' in program
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval updateInterval; //May be capped at ...
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:46:1: error: 
      unexpected '@' in program
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<UIAccelerometerDelegate> delegate;
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:48:1: error: 
      '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
@end
^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:50:35: error: 
      cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol UIAccelerometerDelegate<NSObject>
                                  ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:53:24: error: 
      expected a type
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UI...
                       ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:53:71: error: 
      expected a type
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAc...
                                                                      ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:53:118: error: 
      expected ':'
  ...didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 5_0);
                                                                   ^
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:53:118: error: 
      expected ';' after method prototype
In file included from <built-in>:181:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from /private/var/easyrespring/theos/Prefix.pch:4:
In file included from /private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10:
In file included from /private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:11:
/private/var/easyrespring/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIBezierPath.h:12:20: error: 
      C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIRectCorner) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.1c1f697b.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [EasyRespring.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Im not sure a better way to post that so I'll leave a link to the ghostbin [here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/3hgog), perhaps it is more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if it's a problem with the SDK headers you are using, the problem seems to be with random files unrelated to your project (According to the easyrespring files on github). Try a different version of the ios 8.1 SDK if you manually downloaded it. Maybe try this one? https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers

Edit:
With the downloaded 8.1 headers you would replace the existing ones in the theos/sdks/ directory. Then you can try running make in your project again to see if it works properly.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still a bit new to this all, I downloaded the headers and now I have a folder named 8.1 but I'm not sure where in my filesystem to place it all? in //var/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk I have my old sdk so would I be placing this IOS8.1 folder in the sdks? Do I delete the iPhoneOS8.1.sdk folder after?

Comment: I might add that currently my //var/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/Developer/Library path only has the folder Frameworks while this IOS8.1 folder has Frameworks, PrivateFrameworks, and SpringBoard, perhaps I paste the IOS8.1 contents in that folder instead?

Comment: I believe theos searches the sdks directory recursively so you should be able to replace the Frameworks dir with the new Frameworks dir and paste the new directories (PrivateFrameworks and SpringBoard) along side it. Just how it is structured in the new downloaded copy. Essentially, It shouldn't matter, just as long as it's not confusingly laid out

Comment: i tried doing this but I still am getting the exact same error. I'm so confused because it doesn't look like its even using the right files

Comment: Which version of easyrespring are you using from github (There are several posted versions) and have you edited any code from it? I can test it out later and see if I get the same errors.

Comment: In addition to using headers,you can just write the header you want manually and add the methods you need. It's much easier to do it that way.

Comment: So I just tried to make a blank project using nic called test, then immediately after instantiating it I tried to run "make test" but I'm getting the exact same error when I try using the easyrespring one, I'm assuming this means it doesn't have anything to do with the specific project.

Comment: Try doing what @AndyIbanez said, delete all the header files in the sdks folder, then just add your own .h files for.. it looks like the SBUIController and add the definition for -(void)finishLaunching; then make it again

Comment: Im heading out for a couple hours and wont have access to a computer but I will try that and comment here when I manage to finish attempting it, sorry for the delay but thanks for the help so far

Comment: I was able to reach a solution here, it appears my headers werent set up properly. https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/338wu3/help_compiling_on_ios/